# Outlook HTMLBody refuses to output the font size I specified, no matter the value

Tags: c#, html, winforms, outlook

I have this code that send email with outlook

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem); 
oMsg.To = "test@test.com";
oMsg.CC = "test1@test.com";
oMsg.Subject = "Fiche De Non-Confoemité N°: " + txtOrderNumber.Text+"/"+ txtCreationDate.DateTime.Year; 
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML; 
oMsg.Display(false); 
oMsg.HTMLBody = "<font size='18px'>"+"Un nouveau fiche de non-confoemité a été ajouté: "+ 
                "<br />" + "N°: " + txtOrderNumber.Text + "/" + txtCreationDate.DateTime.Year +
                "<br />" + "Détecteur: " + cmbDetecteurStructure.Text +
                "<br />" + "Personne Concernée: " + cmbRelevantEmployee.Text +
                "<br />" + "Date: " + txtCreationDate.Text +
                "<br />" + "Crée par « Smart Industrial Management »" +"</font>"+ oMsg.HTMLBody ;
```

I tried different values for the font-size (14, 16, 18, 20) but it always end up with the same size (10) in outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text in some block, `span` for example, and add `style` to it:

```
<span style=\"font-size:16px\">Un nouveau fiche de non-confoemité a été ajouté:</span>
```

or just apply `style` to your `font` tag:

```
<font style=\"font-size:16px\">
```

Comment: I used: strMessageBody = string.Format("<font face='Calibri' font style=\'font-size:14.5\'>{0}<font/>", sbMessageBody.Replace("\r\n", "<br>"));
And received the output I wanted.
sbMessageBody is built using StringBuilder
objMessage.Display(null);
objMessage.HTMLBody = strMessageBody + objMessage.HTMLBody;
14.5 gave a font size in my Outlook 2010 email of 11. 14 gave 10.5, and 15 gave 11.5.